# How to write structure into a file in c++ and send them through zigbee

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, structure, zigbee

I have tried 3 methods to write the structure to a .txt or .dat file .It write the file in given path but when i open this file then it shows only some ASCII character and not shown 1*1 structure. These structure variables are required to accessed using matlab as it is .
My code for c++ is below:-

```
struct packet{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double M;
    int B;
    Mat phi;
    Mat y;
};
int main()
 {
 packet DATA[6];
 DATA[1].rows=m;
 DATA[2].cols=n;
 DATA[3].M=M;
 DATA[4].B=B;
 DATA[5].phi=phi;
 DATA[6].y=y;

// 1st method to write to file//
 fstream binary_file("DATA.mat");
 binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&DATA),sizeof(DATA));
 binary_file.close();

// 2nd method
 ofstream myfile12 ("DATA.txt");
 if (myfile12.is_open())
 {
  myfile12 << &DATA[1]<<&DATA[2]<<&DATA[3]<<&DATA[4]<<&DATA[5]<<&DATA[6];

  myfile12.close();
 }
 else cout << "Unable to open file";

// 3rd method//
 FILE *out
outfile = fopen (DATA.dat","w");
 if (outfile == NULL)
 {
 fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening accounts.dat\n\n");
 exit 
}
 fwrite (&DATA, sizeof(DATA), 1, outfile);
return 0;
}
```

I need the output like this to access these variables through matlab:-

```
DATA.rows=m;
 DATA.cols=n;
 DATA.M=M;
 DATA.B=B;
 DATA.phi=phi;
 DATA.y=y;
```

Here the values of m=480;n=640;M=87;B=16;and by using 2nd method I am able to write the Mat phi and y into a text file.
The second mehod produced the output like this:-

```
0x28f2300x28f2b80x28f3400x28f3c80x28f4500x28f4d8
```

The 1st and 3rd method produced the output :-

```
lûÌo ýÌo              ÿB                                    Äñ( ìñ(           ÿB                                    üñ( $ò(             à                     ÿB                                    Lò( tò(           ÿB                                    „ò( ¬ò(         ¸ó( !   €   !             ÿB                                    Ôò( üò(           ÿB                                     
ó( 4ó(         tó( ì )          ÀU@      ÿB                                    \ó( „ó(           ÿB                                    ”ó( ¼ó(         àó(  ÷( Ðö(     l         ÿB                                    äó(  
ô(           ÿB                                     ô( Dô(                                  @ÿB    W       €[T € W €[T € W € W     lô( ”ô(           ÿB                                    ¤ô( Ìô(         Ã 'D
```

Please suggest me how can I save these variables into a file and also send them through a serial communication (xbee or zigbee).

Thank u for any help

Comment: Does the `Mat` object contain any pointers? Writing and restoring pointers from binary files won't work.

Comment: No ,it contains only floating point values (double).

Comment: So fixed sized arrays of double?

Comment: yes for example-193.7307350451894;
  275.6401327067971;
  115.6809425089981;
  194.5884250730598;
  -428.3089576676988;
  -121.2559276901546;
  427.8801126537638;

Comment: Show the struct or class declaration please.

Comment: Mat y is one column matrix, mat phi is 87*256 column matrix

Comment: struct declaration is given in code and i am not using class .Whole code is written in one file in QT

Comment: struct packet{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double M;
    int B;
    Mat phi;
    Mat y;
};

Comment: The `Mat` declaration dude!

Comment: cv:: Mat hadamard1 = generateHadamardMatrix(int(log2(N)));
  cv:: Mat hadamard =Mat(N,N,CV_64FC1);
  gemm(hadamard1,r1,1.0,noArray(),0.0,hadamard);

Comment: Have you looked at JSON encoding your data for transmission? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: @khushbu30 Of course `cv::Mat` maintains pointers internally, you can't simply store it into a binary file. You need some serialization and deserialization mechanism.

Comment: Can you please tell more about serialization and deserialization mechanism or give some related link

Comment: JSON is in JAVA format...How to do this in c++? I dont know JAVA.